# Send accept-line to readline when binding the Enter key using bash bind -x

Tags: bash, readline

I have successfully bind the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key using:

```bsh
function foo() {
  echo 'Im a foo'
}

bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-M": foo'
```

the problem is I have no way of accepting the READLINE_LINE.

How can I bind the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to an external command then send an accept line as the same time?

I have tried printing newline using this:

```bsh
function foo() {
  echo 'Im a foo'
  printf "%b" "\n"
}
```

but that's just prints a newline after the prompt. not actually accepting the READLINE_LINE.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems not possible to invoke readline's standard accept-line behaviour in a custom enter handler, you can use this: https://github.com/axiros/readline_proxy/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.